# C - send multiple messages over a single socket - Data not transferred until I close the socket

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, send

I am attempting to have a TCP communication from my laptop to a SoC board where I send one message to initiate a process and It sends me a series of status messages until it has completed the process. This means that I would call send() multiple times over the socket from the SoC. The problem is that my laptop does not receive any status message unless the socket connection is closed by the SoC. As soon as the socket closes, I get a burst of all the data that the SoC sent. Is there a way to make this communication realtime so that I get the status messages immediately as it sends?

Code on the SoC that sends the data: This function is called multiple times:

```
INT16 upload(INT16* socket, INT8 HOB, INT8 LOB, INT8 msg_type, INT8* data) {
    INT8* Tx_Data= NULL;
    INT8 size = 0;
    INT16 num= 0;
    int temp = 0;
    size = 256*HOB + LOB + NAME_SIZE + 3;
    Tx_Data = (INT8*) malloc(size*sizeof(INT8));
    for (num=0;num<NAME_SIZE ;num++) {
            Tx_Data[num] = NAME[num];   
    }   
    Tx_Data[num++] = HOB;
    Tx_Data[num++] = LOB;
    Tx_Data[num++] = msg_type; // 11 byte header ends here
    for(temp = 0;num<size;num++,temp++) {
        Tx_Data[num] = data[temp]; // data
    }
    send(*socket, (INT8*)Tx_Data,num,0);
    return PASS;
}
```

Code on my Laptop:

```
for(;;) {
            printf("Start of for loop socket id: %d \n",socket_id);
            RX_Data = (unsigned char*)malloc(2048);
            unsigned char Command;
            int No_of_Data_Bytes=0;
            printf("Before read.... \n");
            nbytes = read(socket_id,RX_Data,11);    // get 11 bytes from EZ80
            printf("Received %d bytes from socket\n",nbytes);
            No_of_Data_Bytes = RX_Data[8]*256 + RX_Data[9];
            Command = RX_Data[10];
            printf("\n command:%c %d \n",Command,No_of_Data_Bytes);
            if(Command=='I' || Command=='E'|| Command=='V') {
                    //read and analyse data
            }
            else {
                    break;
            }
            Command = '\0';
            free(RX_Data);
        }
```

Comment: You are not guaranteed to get 11 bytes on every read.  You have to read in a loop until you are sure you have the full request.  That may or may not be your problem but it isn't helping.

Comment: @Duck I am sure that I am sending 11 bytes.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you send.  TCP will break it up for transmission however it wants and what you send may or may not be what you get in a read.  You have to read in a loop until you are sure you get 11 bytes.

Comment: Look at TCP_NODELAY on the `send`.  That will force TCP to send your 11 bytes on every write which, I think, is what you are getting at.  Otherwise tcp may collect your `send` data in a buffer until it think it is optimal to send it.  That's probably why you are seeing a blast at the close.  And change the read.

Comment: Yes I will change the read.. My SoC does not support TCP_NODELAY flag.send has only one flag that it supports which is the PSH flag. Are both the same? If not,Is there any other alternative way of doing it?

Comment: I have no experience with that but from the little I read it sounds like PSH is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux you could just use `fdopen`, write and flush the stream. Not sure if it's applicable in your case however. Example:

```
FILE *f = fdopen(socketdescriptor, "w+");
. . .
n = write(socketdescriptor, "this is a message", 17);
fflush(f);
...
```

Comment: Thats essentially what I did on my laptop but I cant do the same on the SoC since it has its own kernel called the Real Time Zilog Kernel which I guess is a non *nix kernel.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this behaviour is Nagel algorithm that is enabled on a socket by default. You can disable it via `setsockopt()` call.

You can use `fflush()` or just add '\n' character to the end of string being writen into the socket, but this will flush only stdio buffers in userland, which is not what you aim at.

Comment: If this is OP's problem - and I'm not sure it is - the easiest solution is to do the `read` properly.  Newlines and `fflush` should have no effect on TCP.  It will flush the stdio buffers but it is meaningless to tcp.